# MySQL Join duplicate result set, how can I solve the issue?

Tags: mysql, sql

****Tables List****

Here I am going to explain relationship between tables.

**Table: campain**

(1.*) (id, campain_id)

**Table: prospect_list_campaigns**

(1.*) prospect_list_id, prospect_list_id

**Table: prospect_lists_prospects**

(1.*) related_id, contact_id

**Table: call_campaign**

***As well as call_campaign table, remind_call also linked to 
prospect_lists_prospects table.***

**Table: prospect_lists_prospects**

(1.*) related_id, contact_id

**Table: remind_call**

When I run this without remind_campaign, **it gives this duplicated output**

```
abc cam | 2
cam 2 | 2
cam 2 | 2
abc cam | 3
cam 2 | 3
cam 2 | 3
```

and MySQL is

```
SELECT  campaigns.name as name, call_campaign.id as call_done
FROM campaigns
JOIN prospect_list_campaigns ON prospect_list_campaigns.campaign_id = campaigns.id
JOIN prospect_lists_prospects ON prospect_lists_prospects.prospect_list_id = prospect_list_campaigns.prospect_list_id
JOIN call_campaign ON call_campaign.cantact_id = prospect_lists_prospects.related_id
WHERE prospect_lists_prospects.related_id = '12'
```

and If I add remind_call table like this, **it gives a NOTHING**,

MySQL is

```
SELECT  campaigns.name as name, call_campaign.id as call_done, remind_campaign.id as call_remind
FROM campaigns
JOIN prospect_list_campaigns ON prospect_list_campaigns.campaign_id = campaigns.id
JOIN prospect_lists_prospects ON prospect_lists_prospects.prospect_list_id = prospect_list_campaigns.prospect_list_id
JOIN call_campaign ON call_campaign.cantact_id = prospect_lists_prospects.related_id
JOIN remind_campaign ON remind_campaign.contact_id = prospect_lists_prospects.related_id
WHERE prospect_lists_prospects.related_id = '12'
```

I am trying here to retrieve all campaign data related to that contact(id 12).
what i want to get if contact get call and remind call about campaign.

can someone please help me to fix this error..thank you

Comment: u have a create table schema you can offer? also, how about using table aliases so you don't have a mispelling

Comment: misspelling rather :>

Comment: @DrewPierce You correct that error was misspelling, I fixed it, now it did give any result, how can i write this sql

Comment: could you please plop together a sample create with inserts like i did here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30547993/generate-unique-ai-id-over-multiple-data-tables/30548826#30548826

Comment: then i will fire off a proposed answer (or someone else will) thx